# Ruby on Rails will_paginate - NoMethodError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, will-paginate

I am trying to paginate my List of Items but somehow its not working. I am pretty new to ruby.

I installed will_paginate by adding `gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.0.5'` to the gemfile and running `bundle install` in the console.

After that I changed my controller to look like

```
def index
  #@productions = Production.all
  @productions = Production.paginate(:per_page => 25, :page => params[:page])
end
```

and to my `index.html.erb` file I added:

```
<h1>Listing productions</h1>
<%= link_to 'New production', new_production_path %>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>Time</th>
    <th>Area</th>
    <th>Items</th>
  </tr>

  <% @productions.each do |production| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= production.date.strftime("%m/%d/%Y") %></td>
      <td><%= production.timefrom.strftime("%H:%M") %> to <%= production.timeto.strftime("%H:%M") %></td>
      <td><%= production.area %></td>
      <td><%= production.items %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Show', production_path(production) %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_production_path(production) %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', production_path(production),
                    method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
<%= will_paginate @productions %>
```

But it still comes up with this error when I reload the page:

```
NoMethodError in ProductionsController#index
undefined method `paginate' for #<Class:0x5225898>
```

Can someone tell me why? Or give me a hint?

Comment: Did you restart your dev server?

Comment: Oh my god. I think that was it...

Comment: I'm quite sure it was.

Comment: Great, basically it works now
but if I add 
`def index

   #@productions = Production.all
   @productions = Production.paginate(:per_page => 25, :page => params[:page], :order => 'Date')
 end` 

it still comes up with an error?

Comment: it comes up with 
`
NoMethodError in ProductionsController#index
undefined method `apply_finder_options' for #<Production::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x530f958>`

Comment: got it. `.order()` has to be done outside the brackets

Comment: now how can i select your answer if its a comment?

Comment: You can't. I created an answer so you can mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should restart your dev server.